# Image upload with zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, image-uploading

I am new to the zend framework. I need to create a user registration with image upload. I have done that. My registration controller and upload controller works. Currently all images are uploading to `uploads/user-images/` in public folder. But my actual requirement is, I have to create a specific folder for each user based on their user ID and need to upload their photos to that folder. Also, I need to store that image path in a DB as `actualname_current_Timestamp_width_height.extension`, but I don't know how to do this. Here I am including my controller codes:

```
<?php
/**
 * PhotoController class file
 *
 * This file contains a class for PhotoController
 *
 * @category Zend
 * @package Zend_Controller
 *
 */

class PhotoController extends Daddara_Controller_BaseController
{
    public $session;

    function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/resources/js/upload.js');
        $this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/resources/js/jquery.min.js');
        $this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/resources/js/jquery.wallform.js');
        $this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/resources/js/modernizr.custom.js');
    //  $this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/resources/js/lightbox/jquery-1.10.2.min.js');
    //  $this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/resources/js/lightbox/lightbox-2.6.min.js');
    }

    function indexAction()
    {

        $this->_forward('upload');
    }

    /**
     * Upload Action action
     *
     */
    public function uploadAction()
    {
        $path = "uploads/user-images/";
        $shortPath = "uploads/user-images/resize/";
        function getExtension($str)
        {

            $i = strrpos($str,".");
            if (!$i) {
                return "";
            }

            $l = strlen($str) - $i;
            $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
            return $ext;
        }

        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        //User Id
        $userId = $em->getRepository("Models\User")->findOneBy(array('id' => $this->currentUser->id));

        //Registration Id
        $registrationId = $em->getRepository("Models\Registration")->findOneBy(array('user' => $this->currentUser->id));

        $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg","PNG","JPG","JPEG","GIF","BMP");
        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
            {
                $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
                $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];


                if(strlen($name))
                {
                    $ext = getExtension($name);
                    //echo $ext;exit;
                    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                    {
                        if($size<(1024*1024))
                        {
                            $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $ext), 5).".".$ext;

                            $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];


                            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                            {
                                if($ext=="jpg" || $ext=="jpeg" )
                                {
                                    $uploadedfile = $path.$actual_image_name;
                                    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
                                }
                                else if($ext=="png")
                                {
                                    $uploadedfile = $path.$actual_image_name;
                                    $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
                                }

                                list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);

                                $newwidth=160;
                                $newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
                                $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

                                imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

                                $filename = "uploads/user-images/resize/". $actual_image_name;

                                imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);

                                $photos = new Models\ProfilePhotos();
                                $photos->setUser($userId)
                                        ->setRegistration($registrationId)
                                        ->setPhoto($path.$actual_image_name)
                                        ->setShortImage($shortPath.$actual_image_name)
                                        ->setAddedOn();

                                $em->persist($photos);
                                $em->flush();
                                echo "<img src='/uploads/user-images/resize/".$actual_image_name."'  class='preview'>";

                            }
                            else
                                echo "Fail upload folder with read access.";
                        }
                        else
                            echo "Image file size max 1 MB";
                    }
                    else
                        echo "Invalid file format..";
                }

                else
                    echo "Please select image..!";

                exit;
            }       

        }
    }

    public function listAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $photo = $em->getRepository('Models\ProfilePhotos')->findBy(array('user' => $this->currentUser->id));
        //print_r($image);exit;
        $this->view->photo = $photo;
    }

    /**
     * delete function
     */
    function deleteAction()
    {
        $deleteId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        if(empty($deleteId)){
            throw new Zend_Controller_Exception("Page not found", 404);
        }

        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $del = $em->find("Models\ProfilePhotos", $deleteId);
        $em->remove($del);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addMessage('Data Deleted Successfully "');
        $this->_redirect('/photo/list');

    }

}
```

Comment: this may help :http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.file.transfer.introduction.html

Comment: @v.eigler: thanks a lot for your help..but that link not contains any necessary informations for my requirement..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder with the command [mkdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php):

```
if(mkdir(APPLICATION_PATH . '/public/uploads/' . $userId)){
   //dir created

}
```

You can move a file with [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) and [unlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php):

```
if(copy(APPLICATION_PATH . '/public/uploads/' .$filename, 
   APPLICATION_PATH . '/public/uploads/' .$userId .'/' .$newfilename)) {
  unlink(APPLICATION_PATH . '/public/uploads/' . $filename);
}
```

Comment: when i tried to use this, it showing notice as  Undefined variable: userdir.. Actually, am getting the id of user in $userId and i need to use this for making that directory if it not exist already and need to store that user photos within this directory and a link to that images within the db..

Comment: You can change the variable names to your prefered name. But if you have problems to implement the solution you should read more php and zend framework tutorials.

Comment: Thanks..I have given some thing like this and i dono whether this way is correct or not..  its showing mkdir() permision denied                            $userId = $em->getRepository("Models\User")->findOneBy(array('id' => $this->currentUser->id));
  
 
           $user_path = '$path.$userId';

           if (!file_exists($user_path)) mkdir($user_path);

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something like the following code and thats worked for me. Now i can upload images to a purticular folder for each user based on their user id. Hope this will help someone else.. :-)

```
            $path = "uploads/user-images/";

            $em = $this->getEntityManager();

            //User Id
            $userId = $em->getRepository("Models\User")->findOneBy(array('id' => $this->currentUser->id));

            $user_path = "$path".$userId->getId()."/";

            if (!file_exists($user_path)) mkdir($user_path, 0777);
```